# Appengine java project with additional runtimes

Tags: google-app-engine, runtime, google-compute-engine

I am struggling, and failing, to create a Java project on appengine which should use a nodejs server running in the same project in a managed vm.
Anyone knows of an example/template for appengine projects with multiple runtimes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just upload them all to the same "project" with different named modules. One of you modules will have to be "default" and the rest are just other named modules in the same project.  I think you can just set vm=true on both projects so that they're managed-vm modules, not regular appengine modules (there might be some extra config here for managed-vms).

For instance you have one java module with an `appengine-web.xml` that looks like

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>my-modules-app</application>
  <module>default</module>
  <version>1</version>
  <vm>true</vm> // for managed-vm
  ...
  ...
</appengine-web-app>
```

I've never tried node on appengine, but with a second module in python you could configure your app.yaml (same application, different module)

```
application: my-modules-app
module: non-default-module
version: 1
vm: true // for managed-vm
runtime: python27
...
```

Presumably, you just need to configure the node.js project correctly to upload to the same application with a different module name.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the way to go. However, I am building with Maven and running devserver with "mvn gcloud:run" and I have no idea how to get maven/gcloud to recognize the nodejs-module... I guess it has to be included in the ear-projects pom/application.xml/maven-application.xml(?). Is it possible to include a nodejs project (in this case a managed vm custom runtime) in a appengine java/maven project?

Comment: So I guess my problem is about how to get the gcloud-maven-plugin to understand that there is a nodejs-project that should be copies into the ear target directory and included in the "gcloud preview app run" command...

Comment: I think there is a provision to specify the location of another app directory when using maven. You can also call down directly to "gcloud", however, I'm not sure that works in the case of node.  Here's the info on the gcloud command which, I believe, works for java/python/go : https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/app/run

Comment: oops, I think I was wrong here : you can run node directories with gcloud : https://cloud.google.com/solutions/nodejs/#quickstart-run

Comment: So you might be able to gcloud run from the commandline :
`gcloud preview app run "path-to-java-webapp" "path-to-nodejs-app"` I'm not super familiar with the maven plugin, but you might be able to specify the locatino of additional webapps (to include your node webapp)